# How to get negative word samples in Gensim Word2Vec Model?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I am using gensim Word2Vec model to train word embeddings. My code is:

```
w2v_model = Word2Vec(min_count=20,
                     window=2,
                     vector_size=50,
                     sample=6e-5,
                     alpha=0.03,
                     min_alpha=0.0007,
                     negative=20,
                     workers=cores-1)

w2v_model.build_vocab(sentences, progress_per=10000)

w2v_model.train(sentences, total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=50, report_delay=1)
```

I wonder whether I can access the negative and positive word samples during the process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Deep inside the training loops, for each individual 'center' word in the training texts that is to be predicted – a micro-training-example for the shallow neural-net – a *different* set of negative words will be chosen.

Those negative-words will be used for just that one set of forward/backward neural-net nudges, then discarded when training moves to the next word.

There's no way to access them other than changing that core code – which is actually written in Cython, & re-compiled into a native library after any changes. (It's a bit harder to tinker with than pure Python code.)

You can see where the exact choice-of-negative samples happens in the source code for one of the modes (CBOW w/ negative-sampling) here:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/91175ddc7e3d6f3a2af245c20af21ec3bf5e360f/gensim/models/word2vec_inner.pyx#L427

If you just need a representative set of negative-words, you could copy these steps in your own code.

If you want to know (& potentially log?) the negative words chosen for *every* positive prediction, I suspect that's a misguided idea:

- Meaningful analysis of this algorithm's behavior won't depend on either individual micro-examples, nor the arbitrarily-random negative words chosen over all training. The interesting properties only arise from the tug-of-war happening across the interplay of all training.
- As this is very deep in the training loops, even the most-efficient extra-steps, as a function of the negative-words, would slow things down a lot. Or, in the case of logging, result in 20x (for `window=20`) more logged-negative-words than your original training corpus. For the kinds of large corpora where this algorithm works well, such a slowdown/log could be onerous; for tiny toy-sized examples, this algorithm won't be working interestingly at all.

So the mere question, if you truly want a peek at *all* the (random, arbitrary) negative words during the process, suggests you may be going down a questionable path.

It'd be easier for me to imagine just wanting to see a representative set of the negatively-sampled words - because any 10, or 10,000, or 1,000,000 such randomly-chosen words are as good as any other, and the algorithm (on adequately-sized data) is robust against usual variance in which negative-words are actually chosen. And for that, you could just run the same sampling-process outside the training.

Separately: those are odd non-default choices for `alpha` & `min_alpha` - values that usually don't need any tweaking, and if tweaked should really only be done so with a conscious plan, driven by quantitaive evaluations comparing the results of alternate values. But, those specific odd unmotivated values are pretty common in some of the **worst** online tutorials. So beware where you're learning about word2vec!